# error in evaluating the argument 'j' in selecting a method for function '[': undefined columns selected

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm trying to run [MuSiC2](https://jiaxin-fan.github.io/MuSiC2/articles/introduction.html).

First, I prepared the input, which comprises `bulk.eset` and `sc.eset`.
There are two conditions, namely `normal` and `KIRP`, which can be found in `bulk.normal` and `bulk.KIRP` respectively.
The `sc.eset` is the single-cell reference matrix.

```
library(Biobase)
library(MuSiC2)
library(data.table)

bulk.normal <- bulk.normal[rownames(bulk.normal) %in% rownames(bulk.kirp),]
bulk.kirp <- bulk.kirp[rownames(bulk.kirp) %in% rownames(bulk.normal),]
bulk.all <- cbind(bulk.kirp, bulk.normal)
labels <- rep(c("KIRP", "normal"), c(ncol(bulk.kirp), ncol(bulk.normal)))
group <- data.frame(t(labels))
samp <- c(names(bulk.kirp), names(bulk.normal))
names(group) <- samp
sampleID <- colnames(bulk.all)
bulk.sampleID <- data.frame(labelDescription=sampleID)
bulk.sampleID <- AnnotatedDataFrame(bulk.sampleID)
bulk.group <- data.frame(labelDescription=group)
bulk.group <- AnnotatedDataFrame(bulk.group)
bulk.eset <- new("ExpressionSet", exprs=as.matrix(bulk.all))
phenoData(bulk.eset) <- bulk.group


sc.df <- as.data.frame(sc.matrix)
rownames(sc.df) <- sc.df[,1]
sc.df[,1] <- NULL
sc.meta$sampleID <- sub(".*?_", "", rownames(sc.meta))
sc.metadata <- data.frame(labelDescription=colnames(sc.meta))
sc.meta.anno <- AnnotatedDataFrame(sc.meta, varMetadata=sc.metadata)
sc.eset <- new("ExpressionSet", exprs=as.matrix(sc.df))
sc.eset@phenoData <- sc.meta.anno
```

When I run MuSiC2, it failed with the following error:

```
est.prop <- music2_prop(bulk.eset=bulk.eset, sc.eset=sc.eset, condition='clust', 
                       control='normal', case='KIRP', clusters='cell_ontology_class', samples='sampleID', 
                       select.ct=c('kidney epithelial cell','b cell','cd8-positive, alpha-beta t cell','endothelial cell','macrophage','nk cell','cd4-positive helper t cell'), 
                       n_resample=20, sample_prop=0.5,cutoff_c=0.05,cutoff_r=0.01)$Est.prop
```

Traceback:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'j' in selecting a method for function '[': undefined columns selected
```

Input:

```
> dput(bulk.kirp[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A = c(7.65342121905285, 6.35598354101006, 
14.3511850042327, 10.3737643425674, 10.0819596419255), TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A = c(5.09389393824392, 
6.93597002271109, 12.4136523086721, 11.1918237390263, 10.1912122382252
), TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A = c(4.70168212029528, 7.54694769203808, 10.1689338100564, 
9.96839262629172, 9.87305770150294), TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A = c(7.99645936536463, 
6.89258167250936, 13.6832285748428, 10.3714563849361, 10.4176870383992
), TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A = c(5.13719199914349, 6.92859654071157, 12.0367193976262, 
10.8202555636581, 10.3262700402849)), row.names = c("A1BG", "A2LD1", 
"A2M", "A4GALT", "AAAS"), class = "data.frame")

> dput(bulk.normal[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(TCGA.BQ.7051.11A = c(57.4382, 1928.9092, 16482.7822, 
1150.8932, 619.0802), TCGA.DZ.6132.11A = c(70.6982, 173.5022, 
36833.3219, 1489.626, 712.553), TCGA.CZ.4864.11A = c(12.9899, 
2416.7342, 31651.9804, 837.9322, 575.9693), TCGA.KN.8426.11A = c(47.5866, 
279.0018, 35180.2554, 644.7446, 684.0869), TCGA.CZ.5982.11A = c(11.257, 
3387.5714, 19067.2504, 720.4503, 513.6544)), row.names = c("A1BG", 
"A2LD1", "A2M", "A4GALT", "AAAS"), class = "data.frame")

> dput(sc.matrix[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(gene = c("DDX11L1", "WASH7P", "MIR6859-1", "MIR1302-2HG", 
"MIR1302-2"), AAACCCAAGTCGGGAT_TSP2_Kidney_NA_10X_1_1 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AAACCCACATGTGTCA_TSP2_Kidney_NA_10X_1_1 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AAACCCAGTCTGCATA_TSP2_Kidney_NA_10X_1_1 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AAACCCATCGAACGCC_TSP2_Kidney_NA_10X_1_1 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x2b091b62d260>)

> dput(sc.meta[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(method = c("10X", "10X", "10X", "10X", "10X"), 
    n_counts_UMIs = c(7147, 25970, 4940, 20438, 5288), Expressed.Genes = c(2122L, 
    5207L, 2097L, 4056L, 1679L), cell_ontology_class = c("kidney epithelial cell", 
    "kidney epithelial cell", "kidney epithelial cell", "kidney epithelial cell", 
    "kidney epithelial cell"), free_annotation = c("kidney epithelial cell", 
    "kidney epithelial cell", "kidney epithelial cell", "kidney epithelial cell", 
    "kidney epithelial cell")), row.names = c("AAACCCAAGTCGGGAT_TSP2_Kidney_NA_10X_1_1", 
"AAACCCACATGTGTCA_TSP2_Kidney_NA_10X_1_1", "AAACCCAGTCTGCATA_TSP2_Kidney_NA_10X_1_1", 
"AAACCCATCGAACGCC_TSP2_Kidney_NA_10X_1_1", "AAACGAAAGTAACAGT_TSP2_Kidney_NA_10X_1_1"
), class = "data.frame")
```